# Passing values from id element and calculate price

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a small pricing calculator. I am passing variables from id elements(**complex**,**subject**,**number_quiz**) to formula to calculate and output results to id variable **total**.

I after passing variables to the formula, it's not calculating and not displaying any results.

```js
function price() {
  var com = document.getElementsById('complex').value;
  var subject = document.getElementsById('subject').value;
  var n_q = document.getElementsById('number_quiz').value;

  if (subject == 5 && com == 10) {
    var total = (com + subject) n_q;
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
  } else if (subject == 7 && com == 10) {
    var total = (com + subject) n_q;
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
  }
  if (subject == 5 && com == 20) {
    var total = (com + subject) n_q;
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
  } else if (subject == 7 && com == 20) {
    var total = (com + subject) n_q;
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Subject</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <select class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" onclick="price()">
        <option default="">Select Subject</option>
        <option value="5">Subject A</option>
        <option value="7">Subject A</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Complexity</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <select class="form-control" name="complex" id="complex">
        <option default>Select Complexity</option>
        <option value="10">Complex Question</option>
        <option value="20">Non Complex Question</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Number of questions</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" name="number_quiz" id="number_quiz" max="9999" min="1" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Total Net</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="total" onkeyup="total()" name="total" class="form-control bg-white border-0">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg w-50 rounded-pill">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there's no multiplying sign (com + subject)n_q - >  (com + subject)*n_q;

Comment: I made you a snippet. It has console errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Missing `*` as already mentioned
2. getElementById is singular
3. Use onChange and add it as an eventListener on the container, added benefit, any change will trigger a calculation
4. You have not told us the manipulation needed in the different ifs, you are missing an else there too
5. `onkeyup="total()"` does not exist, and what is it supposed to do?

Note I cast the values to number usining the unary `+` operator and use 0 if undefined

```js
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('change', function() {
  const com = +document.getElementById('complex').value || 0;
  const subject = +document.getElementById('subject').value || 0;
  const n_q = +document.getElementById('number_quiz').value || 0;
  const total = (com + subject) * n_q;

  if (subject == 5 && com == 10) {
    // ...
  } else if (subject == 7 && com == 10) {
    // ...
  } else if (subject == 5 && com == 20) {
    // ...
  } else if (subject == 7 && com == 20) {
    // ...
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = total;
});
```

```html
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Subject</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <select class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject">
        <option default="">Select Subject</option>
        <option value="5">Subject A</option>
        <option value="7">Subject A</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Complexity</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <select class="form-control" name="complex" id="complex">
        <option default>Select Complexity</option>
        <option value="10">Complex Question</option>
        <option value="20">Non Complex Question</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Number of questions</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" name="number_quiz" id="number_quiz" max="9999" min="1" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Total Net</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" readonly id="total" name="total" class="form-control bg-white border-0">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg w-50 rounded-pill">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

First, I believe you mean `var total = (com + subject) * n_q;` rather than `var total = (com + subject)n_q;`.

Second, all `if` clauses run the same code, so you can remove all the `if` statements and leave the code as.

Third, you need to change `getElementsById` to `getElementById`.

```
function price()
{
    var com = document.getElementById('complex').value;
    var subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
    var n_q = document.getElementById('number_quiz').value;

    var total = (com + subject) * n_q;
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(com + subject)n_q
```

is incorrect. If you want to multiply it should be...

```
(com + subject) * n_q
```

Also the if statements are unnecessary, because you're doing the same action in all of them.

Answer (score 1):

```js
   function price()
    {
    var com = document.getElementById('complex').value;
    var subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
    var n_q = document.getElementById('number_quiz').value;

    if (subject == 5 && com == 10)
    {
        var total = (com + subject)*n_q;
        document.getElementById('total').value = total;
    }
    else if (subject == 7 && com == 10) {
        var total = (com + subject)*n_q;
        document.getElementById('total').value = total;
    }
    if (subject == 5 && com == 20)
    {
        var total = (com + subject)*n_q;
        document.getElementById('total').value = total;
    }
    else if (subject == 7 && com == 20) {
        var total = (com + subject)*n_q;
        document.getElementById('total').value = total;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container py-5">
            <div class="row py-3">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Subject</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <select class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" onclick="price()">
                    <option default="">Select Subject</option>
                    <option value="5">Subject A</option>
                    <option value="7">Subject A</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row py-3">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Complexity</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <select class="form-control" name="complex" id="complex" >
                    <option default>Select Complexity</option>
                    <option value="10">Complex Question</option>
                    <option value="20">Non Complex Question</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row py-3">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Number of questions</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="number" name="number_quiz" id="number_quiz" max="9999" min="1" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="row py-3">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Total Net</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="total"  name="total" class="form-control bg-white border-0">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row py-3">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="button" onclick="price()"  value="Submit"
                class="btn btn-danger btn-lg w-50 rounded-pill">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Error 1**

To do multiplication you need to use *

var total = (com + subject)*n_q;

**Error 2**

In your code, you had document.getElementsById which should be document.getElementById

**Error 3**

In your code on total, you are calling a function total on keyup, which is not defined on your javascript code

**Error 4**

Your calculation function price is never called

Comment: * 4 - yes on click of the first select. there are other issues too